# Why is there a gap on the edges of my website even with width set to 100%?

Tags: html, css

UPDATE: I have included all of my code. I have my width for the body and background images set to 100% and I have a gap around the perimeter of my page. I tried playing with the percentages, margins and padding and nothing so far is working. I do have a background image that is black so it is very noticeable.

Here is some of my CSS:

```
 body {
  background: url("background.png") no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }

 #msg {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 400px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  float: right;
  font-family: "Roboto Mono", monospace;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background: url("background 2.png") no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size: 100%;
  animation: example 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  margin: -10px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    background: url("background.png") no-repeat fixed center;
  }
  25% {
    background: grey;
  }
  50% {
    background: url("background.png") no-repeat fixed center;
  }
  100% {
    background: url("background.png") no-repeat fixed center;
  }
}

.glitch {
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: white;
  font-size: 250px;
  padding-top: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}

.glitch::before,
.glitch::after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 300.5px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.glitch::before {
  left: 5px;
  text-shadow: -1.5px 0 red !important;
  background: black;
  animation: glitch-anim-1 1.89s infinite linear alternate-reverse;
}

.glitch::after {
  left: -10px;
  text-shadow: -1.5px 0 rgb(89, 0, 255);
  background: black;
  animation: glitch-anim-2 1.8s infinite linear alternate-reverse;
}

@keyframes glitch-anim-1 {
  0% {
    clip: rect(100px, 1500px, 150px, 0);
  }
  10% {
    clip: rect(50px, 1500px, 25px, 0);
  }
  20% {
    clip: rect(50px, 1500px, 25px, 0);
  }
  30% {
    clip: rect(50px, 1500px, 400px, 0);
  }
  40% {
    clip: rect(600px, 1500px, 50px, 0);
  }
  50% {
    clip: rect(300px, 1500px, 65px, 0);
  }
  60% {
    clip: rect(100px, 1500px, 150px, 0);
  }
  70% {
    clip: rect(50px, 1500px, 25px, 0);
  }
  80% {
    clip: rect(200px, 1500px, 30px, 0);
  }
  90% {
    clip: rect(600px, 1500px, 50px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    clip: rect(600px, 1500px, 50px, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes glitch-anim-2 {
  0% {
    clip: rect(100px, 1500px, 150px, 0);
  }
  10% {
    clip: rect(50px, 1500px, 25px, 0);
  }
  20% {
    clip: rect(50px, 1500px, 25px, 0);
  }
  30% {
    clip: rect(50px, 1500px, 400px, 0);
  }
  40% {
    clip: rect(600px, 1500px, 50px, 0);
  }
  50% {
    clip: rect(300px, 1500px, 65px, 0);
  }
  60% {
    clip: rect(100px, 1500px, 150px, 0);
  }
  70% {
    clip: rect(50px, 1500px, 25px, 0);
  }
  80% {
    clip: rect(200px, 1500px, 30px, 0);
  }
  90% {
    clip: rect(600px, 1500px, 50px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    clip: rect(600px, 1500px, 50px, 0);
  }
}

.arrow {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 80px;
  margin-top: 6%;
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}

/* -----------
NAVIGATION
------------ */

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center !important;
  background: #fffefe;
  margin: -8px;
  z-index: 2 !important;
}

nav > ul > li {
  padding: 8px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav > ul > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: "Major Mono Display", monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
}

nav > ul > li:hover {
  /* ADD WEBKIT */
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.container {
  background: url("background.png") no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.sectionHead {
  font-family: "Major Mono Display", monospace;
  float: right;
  /* ADD WEBKIT */
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 50px 10px;
}

/* ABOUT  */

.b1 {
  background: #fffefe;
  width: 90%;
  height: 600px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
  float: left;
}

.aboutPic {
  width: 355px;
  height: 325px;
  margin-top: 140px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#description {
  margin-left: 400px;
  margin-right: 200px;
  margin-top: -300px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.name {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1px;
}

.des1 {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.des2 {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

/* SKILLS */

.b2 {
  background: #fffefe;
  width: 90%;
  height: 600px;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
  float: right !important;
}

#skills-text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-left: 700px;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}

#skills-text .title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 200;
  line-height: 2px;
}

#skills-text > ul > li {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 200;
}

#skills {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  text-align: center;
}

#skills p {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
}

i {
  font-size: 48px;
}

.jquery {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.redux {
  margin-top: -2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
}

.boot {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
}

/* PROJECTS  */
.b3 {
  background: #fffefe;
  width: 90%;
  height: 600px;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
  float: left;
}

.projects {
  padding-top: 86px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

figure.display {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 21.5%;
  height: 21.5%;
  color: #646464;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Roboto Mono", monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.projectLi {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: start;
}

figure.display * {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

figure.display img {
  width: 140%;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#link {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid #646464;
  border-radius: 5%;
  color: #646464;
  width: 42%;
  height: 15%;
  margin: 3px;
  padding-left: 0;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
}

#link:hover {
  background: #646464;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: 500ms;
  padding-left: -10px;
}

#link > i {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #646464;
  background: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

figure.display figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

figure.display:before {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
  background: #c2c1c1;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(110deg) translateY(-50%);
  transform: rotate(110deg) translateY(-50%);
}

figure.display.overlay {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.note {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

/* CONTACT */

.b4 {
  background: #fffefe;
  width: 90%;
  height: 600px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  float: right !important;
}

form {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 400px;
}

input {
  width: 400px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 15px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  background: #fffefe;
}

input::placeholder {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

textarea {
  background: #fffefe;
  height: 100px;
  min-width: 396px;
  max-width: 396px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

textarea::placeholder {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 2px;
}

.submit {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 30px;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: #000000;
  color: #fffefe;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.fa-angle-double-right {
  font-size: 12px;
}

button:hover {
  background: #fffefe;
  color: #000000;
}

.formText {
  text-align: center;
}

/* FOOTER */

footer {
  clear: both;
  background: #fffefe;
  color: #8f8f8f;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -200px;
}

h3 {
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.social {
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-right: 90px;
  float: right;
}

.fli {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #8f8f8f;
  padding: 10px;
}

.fli:hover {
  color: #000000;
  transition: 800ms;
}

.fg {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #8f8f8f;
  padding: 10px;
}

.fg:hover {
  color: #000000;
  transition: 800ms;
}
```

Comment: add a working example like jsfiddle.

Comment: Should body width be 100% instead of 101%?

Comment: Show your full code here.

Comment: you did not publish your code but if i try your `body` definitions it look ok: https://codverter.com/src/webeditor?query=8b78fa3f-24fe-4f6a-bd98-c12315556ba8 we need your complite code.

Comment: @NasyaAS add your html too please? create a snippet or jsfiddle

Answer (score 2):

It is a basic thing that the default margin added in your page .
For Ex :
[Click to see the Default margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlpAT.png)

So you need to remove that. So you have to add the style in your style tag `<style>body {margin:0px;}>`
And you can add your additional styles based on your need.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.img
{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
body
{
margin:0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<image src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" class="img">
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it will help you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Is the margin 8px something that is built in? I don't have that anywhere in my code. I've tried adding the margin 0px to the body itself as you suggested but no improvement

Comment: It is the basic problem that's why I suggest this for you. Beyond that without adding your styles just try my code what I given in the answer box. Check it's work or not?

Comment: I got your problem i think. I've tried this in a different machine it doesn't work. Because it creates another body tag outside when we edit our page body. So you can add the style inside the style tag like `<style>body {margin:0px;}</style>`. Then you can use the body tag without any inline CSS representation.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is the browsers have some default css settings. Search Google for phrase "reset css" and include it before defining your own look :) beware that everything will be then unstyled before you redefine it

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the property of background image...

```
background-size : cover;
```

I think so from this property your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know your html structure, so I am suggesting something that I use mostly,

```
<head>
#..
</head>

<body style="margin: 0;">

    <img class="background">

</body>

<style>
 .background{
    width: 100%;
    height: ..
    ..
  }
</style>
```

What I do is to make body, the whole screen. Margin set to 0 make it 100% screen size with no more margin left.

Then I add my header div or background image or footer inside it instead of adding directly the background image to the body tag. You can make all these 100% or whatever your requirement. There will not be any problem regarding margin.

This is something I use that works fine for me in most cases. Hope this can help you as well.